# Laravel Socialite Facebook Login Error: The parameter app_id is required

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-socialite

Trying to get socialite to work on my app. Facebook returns the `The parameter app_id is required` error.

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/login/facebook', '\CommendMe\Http\Controllers\AuthController@redirectToProvider');

Route::get('/login/facebook/callback', '\CommendMe\Http\Controllers\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

**services.php**:

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('426129694395672'),  
    'client_secret' => env('840fca14fc9fac4b592cd49f285c2ee9'), 
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost/login/facebook/callback',
],
```

**AuthController.php**

```
public function redirectToProvider() {
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}   

public function handleProviderCallback() {
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    $user->name;
}
```

When trying the `/login/facebook` route, facebook returns this error.
Why is this happening?

Comment: well there is no `app_id` obviously

Comment: is that not the 'client_id' in services.php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use as

```
'client_id' => '426129694395672',
```

Or

```
'client_id' => env("FB_APP",'426129694395672'),
```

and use `FB_APP = '426129694395672'`  in `.env` file

Instead

```
'client_id' => env('426129694395672'),
```

Using `env('VarName')`  is to get value of environment variable named as `VarName` in `.env` file

Comment: doh! Yeah, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the following in your `.env` file:

```
CLIENT_ID=426129694395672
CLIENT_SECRET=840fca14fc9fac4b592cd49f285c2ee9
```

The `facebook[]` in your services.php should be like this:

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('CLIENT_ID'),  
    'client_secret' => env('CLIENT_SECRET'), 
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost/login/facebook/callback',
],
```